# microsoft visual studio is busy waiting for an internal operation to complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I browsed a lot but could not find anything that could end up the issue and tried all whatever I found after googling for the same.I tried downloading Microsoft.Jquery.UnObstrusive via Nuget in VS and it started doing that but it turned out to be horrible when I found that it was only saying Installing..... and it went on and could not proceed without anything else but showing the dialog box containing the same message. So I had no option but to stop VS from Task Manager. I did that and now when I open the project I get the dialog box message from the Notifications Area saying Microsoft Visual Studio is busy.......
I could not do anything if I try opening it doesn't respond simply I get the msg.

I tried hitting shift+f5, also ctrl+break, etc; whatever I found after googling but could end without a solution. Anyone do have an answer.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: getting worse for me with VS2015 RC1. I found closing open windows and restarting made huge difference but cannot diagnose the actual problem yet